# Carbocation formation in electrophilic addition of hydrogen halides to alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbocation, regioselectivity

**Question:**
[image: Question]

**My attempt:**

[image: My Approach]

I made the carbocation on the carbon labelled $1$ because I think that the positive charge would be slightly more stable on $1$ compared to $2$ due to the inductive effect of $\ce{Cl}$.

But my teacher made the carbocation on $2$ giving the explanation that *after rearrangement*, the positive charge will be stabilised by resonance with $\ce{Cl}$.
His approach:

[image: Teacher's Approach]

Now, my question is, comparing the stabilities of the carbocation intermediates *without rearrangement*, the positive charge will be stable on $1$ compared to $2$. After rearrangement too, I think that the tertiary carbocation will be more stable than compared to the one stabilized by resonance with $\ce{Cl}$.

So, what is wrong in my reasoning?

Or as suggested by Mithoron, will there be intramolecular attack by $\ce{Cl}$?

[image: NGP]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbouring_group_participation

Comment: @Mithoron I don't understand how will be NGP here? If it was that way, the carbocation will be formed on $3$ without $\ce{Cl}$ to stabilise it. It would be very unstable. It would also lead to a different product, $\ce{Cl}$ bonded to $2$.

Comment: Protonation on "1" should be preferred because it leads to cyclic chloronium cation and  indeed a product is different then both of your suggestions.

Comment: @Mithoron I don't think that due to the following reasons. 1) The cyclic chloronium transition state will be 4 membered. It would be highly unstable. It is not even aromatic. 2) The resulting cation after rearrangement of $1$ carbocation will be a tertiary carbocation. So, the intermediate will be much stable compared to the one on $3$ which will be there if it did NGP. This carbocation is primary with nothing to stabilise it.

Comment: 3) I think it 1,2 - Hydride shifts would be faster than the $\ce{Cl}$ attacking from a distance of 2 carbons in between. $\ce{Cl}$ attacking will require more work compared to $\ce{H}$ as $\ce{Cl}$ is much heavier than $\ce{H}$.

Comment: 3-membered, exactly your second scenario, but no hydride shift.  Instead chloronium and then ring opening.

Comment: @Mithoron Is Hydride shift faster than the intramolecular attack of $\ce{Cl}$? Are the rates comparable? If yes, then I think we will get a mixture of different products. I don't know which will be major or minor.

Comment: @Mithoron I've edited the question. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: Is there a way to predict when these kinds of nucleophilic attacks occur?

Answer (score 7):

The rate determining step is carbocation formation. After which, depending on conditions, the trapping of the cation may or may not be slow enough for [1,2]-shifts.

The [1,2]-shifts are probably under thermodynamic control if there is time for them to take place. This means that if there's time for the shifts, we're hunting for the most stable cation. Otherwise, you trap the most readily formed cation in a kinetic sense (which is not necessarily the most stable).

Assuming shifts are fast, I think your solution is better because the tertiary cation is more stable. Dichloromethane doesn't undergo substitution as easily as t-butyl chloride, so I would have to argue that the tertiary carbocation is more stable.

Comment: I think in this case, both kinetic and thermodynamic factors help the formation of carbonation at $1$.

Comment: You've already assumed the kinetic factor doesn't matter because it would mean that you would trap the cation where it's first formed without any migration.

Comment: As suggested by Mithoron, is there any chance of intramolecular attack by $\ce{Cl}$?

Comment: That's actually a really good suggestion, and probably better than either of the proposals you've presented to pick from. The chloronium ion is the accepted intermediate for halogenation of alkenes. This is an interesting way to access the intermediate.

Comment: Given the bond angles involved, I'm not convinced that the intramolecular attack is very likely.  Even though the chloronium ion is the accepted intermediate in the chlorination of alkenes, the mechanism of formation is completely different.

Comment: @MichaelLautman I would still consider it by microscopic reversibility arguments. I don't have access to literature searches anymore, but if this is possible, I would suspect that it would have been reported more than once. Want to look?

Comment: @Zhe . I just might.

Comment: @Zhe Can you provide the source of "Dichloromethane does not undergo substitution as easily as t-butyl chloride"?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Experience? I mixed dichloromethane and alchoholic solvents but there's been minimal reaction. On the other hand, t-butyl chloride reacts fairly readily with water/alcoholic solvent mix.

Comment: @Zhe "The chloronium ion is the accepted intermediate for halogenation of alkenes". Are you talking about addition of $\ce{Cl_2}$ or $\ce{Br_2}$?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Yes

Comment: @Zhe Do you think that this question of a worth of a bounty by me?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis No, but it's your reputation, and you should use it as you see fit.